# AYUDA!! Problemas al intentar copiar un archivo por ftp, de un apache con xampp a un servidor AS400

Tags: php, ftp

```
introducir el código aquí
```

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){

```
$fileTemp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];



if ($fileSize > 1000000) {

    $_SESSION['error'] = "El tamaño del archivo no debe ser mayor a 1 MB. ";

    header('Location: ../vista/form.php');


}

if ( $fileType != "image/jpeg" ) {

    $_SESSION['error'] = "El archivo a subir debe estar en formato JPG.";

    header('Location: ../vista/form.php');

}

if (empty($_POST['cta'])) {

    $_SESSION['error'] = "Debe seleccionar un tipo de cuenta.";

    header('Location: ../vista/form.php');
}

//qibm/UserData/WebSphere/AppServer/V7/Express/profiles/WAS70SVR/sbi/sbi.ear/sbi.war/FirmasAH

$servidor = ftp_connect("xx.xx.xx.xx");
$usuarioFtp = ftp_login($servidor, "nbrusquett","xxxx");

if ((!$servidor) || (!$usuarioFtp)) {

    $_SESSION['error'] = "Error en la conexión. "; die;

    header('Location: ../vista/form.php');
} 


    ftp_pasv ($servidor, true);

ftp_chdir($servidor, "/qibm/UserData/WebSphere/AppServer/V7/Express/profiles/WAS70SVR/sbi/sbi.ear/sbi.war/FirmasAH/");

$ruta = "/qibm/UserData/WebSphere/AppServer/V7/Express/profiles/WAS70SVR/sbi/sbi.ear/sbi.war/FirmasAH/".$fileName;

    if (is_uploaded_file($fileTemp)){

        if (move_uploaded_file($fileTemp, $ruta)) {

            $_SESSION['error'] = "Registro de firma cargado correctamente.";

            header('Location: ../vista/form.php');      

        };



    }

    else {

        $_SESSION['error'] = "No se pudo copiar el archivo.";

        header('Location: ../vista/form.php');

    }

    ftp_close($servidor);
```

}

?> Tienen alguna idea de que podria estar mal? **El error que tengo es:**

**Warning: move_uploaded_file(/qibm/UserData/WebSphere/AppServer/V7/Express/profiles/WAS70SVR/sbi/sbi.ear/sbi.war/FirmasAH/nbrusquett.JPG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\CargaRegistroDeFirmas\controlador\cargaFirma.php on line 58
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php7957.tmp' to '/qibm/UserData/WebSphere/AppServer/V7/Express/profiles/WAS70SVR/sbi/sbi.ear/sbi.war/FirmasAH/nbrusquett.JPG' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CargaRegistroDeFirmas\controlador\cargaFirma.php on line 58**

Answer (score 0):

Debes averiguar la ruta donde el servidor guarda temporalmente los archivos puedes desde el php.ini o con phpinfo() y remplazarla por la que tienes puesta que al parecer esta mal.